# Delimited Text within CDATA on XML file

Tags: xml, excel, ms-access

I have an XML file I need to import into either an Excel worksheet or an Access table.  The XML file contains a Header with several fields, and a report body with a CDATA field containing repeating information (delimited text within the CDATA).  Here is the basic version of what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CMCFReport      
xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="CMCReports.xsd"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <HEADER>
      <ModeS>A5A1ED</ModeS>
      <TailNumber>UNKNOWN</TailNumber>
      <Timestamp>
         <Day>1</Day>
         <Month>12</Month>
         <Year>2016</Year>
         <Hour>18</Hour>
         <Minute>36</Minute>
         <Second>58</Second>
       </Timestamp>
   </HEADER>
   <ReportBody>
      <StorageReport>
         <![CDATA[PLF 01DEC16 1835 --------- L
COL3A-0072-001N BCG3F-CMCM-002K
MSG 2158513 01DEC16 1714 TO           A 1  
FDE 21500944 01DEC16 1713 TA           A
FDE 21502445 01DEC16 1713 TA           A
MSG 2158512 01DEC16 1714 TO           A 1
EOR
]]>
    </StorageReport>
  </ReportBody>
</CMCFReport>
```

What I would like the imported data to look like is (fields separated by "/"):

```
A5A1ED/UNKNOWN/1/12/2016/18/36/58/COL3A-0072-001N/BCG3F-CMCM-002K/MSG/2158513/01DEC16/1714/TO/A 1

A5A1ED/UNKNOWN/1/12/2016/18/36/58/COL3A-0072-001N/BCG3F-CMCM-002K/FDE/21500944/01DEC16/1713/TA/A

A5A1ED/UNKNOWN/1/12/2016/18/36/58/COL3A-0072-001N/BCG3F-CMCM-002K/FDE/21502445/01DEC16/1713/TA/A

A5A1ED/UNKNOWN/1/12/2016/18/36/58/COL3A-0072-001N/BCG3F-CMCM-002K/MSG/2158512/01DEC16/1714/TO/A 1A
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this, or am I going to need to dig into VBA to import this data?  I don't have any way to change the format of the XML file.  I've imported delimited text files before but not XML files, so I don't have any experience playing with data in XML.  Thanks.

Comment: CDATA sections will happily contain that text. What's your concern about it?

Comment: Why would you think Excel could import your data that way without you doing anything in VBA or another language first? It has no idea what you want to do with the CDATA (or the rest of the file, for that matter). Excel has gotten pretty powerful, but it hasn't been enabled with psychic mind reading skills yet. :-)

Comment: Luis Munoz, I'm trying to work out how to break that text up into several fields.  A straightforward import puts that whole text section into one cell.  Ken White, fair enough.  I have some experience using VBA with Access, but very little with Excel.  I'm not sure where to start with figuring out how to code the import function.  Also, I'm limited by my workplace on which machines will run macros in Excel.

Comment: As is, this question is too broad. Parsing and splitting that string and parsing the XML and extracting the content of that node are completely independent tasks. Please ask about only one of them.

Comment: I guess I don't know enough to ask the right question.  I just want to know how to tell access how to put this XML file into a table and spell out which data goes into what field.  I really don't know where to start with this.